# how can I create a builder which allows non-consuming and consuming functions

Tags: rust, move, builder

I want to create a builder for a struct representing an analytics event. once the event is "sent" the builder should be consumed.

I read this primer:

https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0/style/ownership/builders.html

so to allow simple chaining without reassignment (which might be required since there are many execution branches), my builder looks like this (simplified)

```
pub struct AnalyticsEvent {

}

impl AnalyticsEvent {
  pub fn new() -> Self {
    AnalyticsEvent { }
  }
 pub fn add_property(&mut self) -> &mut AnalyticsEvent {
        self
    }

// now I want the "send" to consume the event
pub fn send(self) {
/// ....
    }
}
```

link to playground

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fbe9e261a419608f2c592799f22ba9f9

Comment: What's exactly the question here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't mix both in the same chain, since your non-consuming methods only return `&mut T` there's no way for `self`-consuming methods to be called on them.

So either keep the builder interface as-is and replace

```rust
    event.add_property().send();
```

by

```rust
    event.add_property();
    event.send();
```

or change the builder interface to always work on owned objects, requiring the odd reassignment in some cases.

In the latter case you could mitigate the issue by adding convenience methods e.g. a `map` which would enclose the conditional situation:

```rust
    event.add_property()
         .add_property()
         .map(|e| if condition {
             e.add_property()
         } else {
             e
         })
         .add_property()
         .send();
```